# My class is not getting populated when deserializing from a JSON string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON string named `rawdata` in the below format:

```
{
  "Base": {
    "RecordDescriptorWord": "0426",
    "ProcessingIndicator": "1",
    "TimeStamp": "08062018131518",
    "Reserved": "0",
    "IdentificationNumber": "9182736",
    "ConsumerAccountNumber": "000000000000000372513500000221",
    "PortfolioType": "R",
    "AccountType": "0G",
    "DateOpened": "10012014",
    "CreditLimit": "000050000",
    "HighestCredit": "000033486",
    "TermsDuration": "REV",
    "TermsFrequency": "M",
    "ScheduledMonthlyPaymentAmount": "000000445"
  }
}
```

and I'm using this code to deserialize:

```
Base content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Base>(rawdata.Content?.ToString());
```

but my `Base` object is not getting populated. What could be wrong?

```
public class Base
{       
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "RecordDescriptorWord")]
    public string RecordDescriptorWord { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ProcessingIndicator")]
    public string ProcessingIndicator { get; set; }   
}
```

Comment: `public class Root { public Base Base {get; set;}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an empty result because your JSON does not match your class structure.

The JSON represents an object that has a single property `Base` whose value is an object containing 14 other properties, among them `RecordDescriptorWord` and `ProcessingIndicator`.  But your class only represents (part of) the inner object, not the outer.

In short, you need another class, as alluded to in the comments:

```
public class Root
{
    public Base Base { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to deserialize the JSON into this new class:

```
Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(rawdata.Content?.ToString());
```

From there you can get the object you want:

```
Base content = root.Base;
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ukVQmD